# How to authenticate a Firebase user on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, apple-watch

**The Situation**
I am using Firebase as my backend which also handles user authentication.  My users record data on their Apple Watch which is sent to Firebase via a cloud function, they can then pull down the data on their Apple iPhone and review it.  Users log into the app via Firebase on their phone.  Currently I am sending their email and password from the phone to the watch via Apple's Watch Connectivity framework.  This allows me to log them in on the watch as well and generate an auth token.  When data is sent from the watch to firebase the auth token is included which the Firebase function uses to validate the request.

**The Problem**
I don't like the idea of sending the user's email address and password over Apple's Watch Connectivity framework.  I also don't like the idea of storing these details on the keychain so I can get a new auth token when the current one expires.  Apple says these mechanisms are secure but this is really a work around compared to the initial way I wanted to approach this.

Initially I just wanted to pass the auth token and the refresh token from the phone to the watch.  I would then request a new auth token on the watch thru the refresh token when the current auth token expired.  However I really like using Firebase in local development mode and the function of refreshing the auth token doesn't seem to be supported through the local emulator, only through the main Google Cloud Platform which doesn't know anything about my local users.

I am stuck at this point and don't want to carry on with my work around solution and would really appreciate some best practice advice to handle this situation.  Thanks!

Comment: Would this work for you https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6924?

Comment: Thanks Frank!  This feels like a better solution than my work around :)  Looking at the comments on the Github issue someone has had some luck implementing this for an Apple Watch extension.  They don't give any specific info on how they did it but it is encouraging all the same.  I'll give it a go and follow up with them if I get stuck.  I'll let you know how I get on once I've given it a shot.